# Navigating with sherlockactionbar in fragments doesnt work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

my problem is when i click on a action bar item onOptionsItemSelected is called but not working.

I only want the back button to work.
Here is my code, this is in the SherlockFragment file:

```
actionbar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.detailitem1:          
        break;
    case android.R.id.home:
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The menu item is com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.
I added setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreate and tried onCreateView too.

The onBackPressed is this, its in the SherlockFragmentActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Saved = SP.getBoolean("saved", false);
    if ((getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detail") == null)
            | mTwoPane) {
        ready = true;
    } else
        ready = false;
    if (!Saved && ready) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .....
    }else if (Saved && ready){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else {
        someListFragment Fragment = new someListFragment ();
        Fragment .setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        Fragment .setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment, "listview")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

In the onbackpressed the ready is true when we are in two pane mode, so when using tablet, or if we are in the first fragment(so the second is null).

If i press the back button everything works fine, the fragments are replaced.
But when i click on the back button in the action bar it just goes back to a previous activity.

Even if i chage the getActivity().onBackPressed(); onBackPressed's else statement i doesnt work.

Does anyone know whats the solution, what i did wrong?

Comment: *But when i click on the back button in the action bar it just goes back to a previous activity.* - that should be the default behavior. What should happen in your opinion?

Comment: The onbackpressed's else statement, so replace the fragment

Comment: Nevermind i found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i was a bit lazy, i forget that i had a onOptionsItemSelected in my FragmantActivity, and the back button is android.R.id.home everwhere, so i put an if statement there and voila.